# LocaleConfig for Per app language preferences not generated

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-locale

I'm currently working on localization for a native android app using Jetpack Compose (minSdk 24, targetSdk 34).

Following the official reference [Per app language preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#api-implementation), I set all the configurations as described.

The guide reports:

> *Starting with Android Studio Giraffe and AGP 8.1, you can configure your app to support per-app language preferences **automatically**.
> Based on your project resources, **AGP generates the LocaleConfig
> file** and adds a reference to it in the final manifest file, so you
> no longer have to do it manually.*

Currently I'm using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2 version with AGP 8.1.2 but the LocaleConfig file isn't generated when building the project or generating an apk.

Am I missing some other configuration setting that is not reported in the guide ?
Am I still obliged to configure the locale config file manually ?

Comment: So you followed all the steps to achieve automatic LocaleConfig generation, like setting `generateLocaleConfig = true`, right? How do you know that `LocaleConfig` is not generated, where do you look for it?

Comment: Thanks @JanBína for the reply. Yes, I set all the variables as described in the guide. I searched in the whole android project. In addition I'm working on a branch on a Git repo; if the file has been generated it should be present in the list of files ready to be committed.

Comment: No, it won't be in the list of files ready to be committed. It will be inside build folder, which shouldn't be tracked by git. You can search for the generated file in build folder, or you can simply see if there is the Language setting option in app settings and whether it contains correct languages after you install the app.

Comment: I've searched in the build folder and the generated file is present. Thanks!

Comment: What is the LocaleConfig used for?